# Route list can‘t find directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When I use `php artisan route:list` to find, it can't access to my within the folder

[image]

The CategoryController is in the Admin folder.  but `route:list` Only in the  `App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController`  lookup.

[image]

What went wrong?

Comment: the CategoryController is in  App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController

Comment: You can write code here in a good formatted way. So please don't post post screenshots of codes

Comment: sorry! it's the first time I come here to ask questions.This is a question of the command line, there is no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your class inheritance. Where does it inherit? Or no inheritance

Comment: But the problem is resolved.may be move in the folder time seem to have a rough time delay.it's normal now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer